# Batch processing in Torch with ClassNLLCriterion

Tags: lua, neural-network, batch-processing, torch

I'm trying to implement a simple NN in Torch to learn more about it. I created a very simple dataset: binary numbers from 0 to 15 and my goal is to classify the numbers into two classes - class 1 are numbers 0-3 and 12-15, class 2 are the remaining ones. The following code is what i have now (i have removed the data loading routine only):

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'

data = torch.Tensor( 16, 4 )
class = torch.Tensor( 16, 1 )

network = nn.Sequential()

network:add( nn.Linear( 4, 8 ) )
network:add( nn.ReLU() )
network:add( nn.Linear( 8, 2 ) )
network:add( nn.LogSoftMax() )

criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()

for i = 1, 300 do
        prediction = network:forward( data )

        --print( "prediction: " .. tostring( prediction ) )
        --print( "class: " .. tostring( class ) )

        loss = criterion:forward( prediction, class )

        network:zeroGradParameters()

        grad = criterion:backward( prediction, class )
        network:backward( data, grad )

        network:updateParameters( 0.1 )
end
```

This is how the data and class Tensors look like:

```
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1
 0  0  1  0
 0  0  1  1
 0  1  0  0
 0  1  0  1
 0  1  1  0
 0  1  1  1
 1  0  0  0
 1  0  0  1
 1  0  1  0
 1  0  1  1
 1  1  0  0
 1  1  0  1
 1  1  1  0
 1  1  1  1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 16x4]

 2
 2
 2
 2
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 16x1]
```

Which is what I expect it to be. However when running this code, i get the following error on line **loss = criterion:forward( prediction, class )**:

> torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/ClassNLLCriterion.lua:69: attempt to
>   perform arithmetic on a nil value

When i modify the training routine like this (processing a single data point at a time instead of all 16 in a batch) it works and the network successfully learns to recognize the two classes:

```
for k = 1, 300 do
for i = 1, 16 do
        prediction = network:forward( data[i] )

        --print( "prediction: " .. tostring( prediction ) )
        --print( "class: " .. tostring( class ) )

        loss = criterion:forward( prediction, class[i] )

        network:zeroGradParameters()

        grad = criterion:backward( prediction, class[i] )
        network:backward( data[i], grad )

        network:updateParameters( 0.1 )
end
end
```

I'm not sure what might be wrong with the "batch processing" i'm trying to do. A brief look at the ClassNLLCriterion didn't help, it seems i'm giving it the expected input (see below), but it still fails. The input it receives (prediction and class Tensors) looks like this:

```
-0.9008 -0.5213
-0.8591 -0.5508
-0.9107 -0.5146
-0.8002 -0.5965
-0.9244 -0.5055
-0.8581 -0.5516
-0.9174 -0.5101
-0.8040 -0.5934
-0.9509 -0.4884
-0.8409 -0.5644
-0.8922 -0.5272
-0.7737 -0.6186
-0.9422 -0.4939
-0.8405 -0.5648
-0.9012 -0.5210
-0.7820 -0.6116
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 16x2]

 2
 2
 2
 2
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 16x1]
```

Can someone help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experience has shown that `nn.ClassNLLCriterion` expects target to be a **1D tensor** of size `batch_size` or a **scalar**. Your `class` is a 2D one (`batch_size x 1`) but `class[i]` is 1D, that's why your non-batch version works.

So, this will solve your problem:

```
class = class:view(-1)
```

Alternatively, you can replace

```
network:add( nn.LogSoftMax() )
criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()
```

with the equivalent:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyCriterion()
```

The interesting thing is that `nn.CrossEntropyCriterion` is also able to take a **2D tensor**. Why is `nn.ClassNLLCriterion` not?

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem! I also find it interesting that CrossEntropyCriterion can take a 2D tensor but ClassNLLCriterion cannot. Perhaps if i have enough time i will submit a patch or something to Torch.

Comment: Just a note, another solution to the problem is simply to define the class tensor as follows: class = torch.Tensor( 16 ) instead of torch.Tensor( 16, 1 ). Both are the same from a logical point of view (16 x 1 == 16 ), but for the criterion interface the two fundamentally differ.

Comment: @PeterK, yep, class:view(-1) does the same thing.

Comment: I found that `nn.CrossEntropyCriterion` is not able to take a 1d tensor...